# Show error message in a tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, passwords

I've a user registration form and I want to show the password rules in small tool tip along with the validation message like invalid password or valid password.My password rule is it contains 7 letters, 1 digit and 1 upper case letter etc.

Currently I've both of these but showing it in two different tool tip how can I merge two and show it in a single one.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<script>
function validatePassword(obj) {
    //rule contains 7 chars and upper case and lower case and digit
    var password = obj.value;
    var numLowers = 0;
    var numCaps = 0;
    var numDigits = 0;
    var valid = true;
    if(password.length > 7) {
        for(i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            var charCode = password.charCodeAt(i);
            if(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 58 )
            numDigits++;
            else if(charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 )
            numCaps++;
            else if(charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 )
            numLowers++;
        }
        if(numDigits < 1 || numCaps < 1 )
        valid = false;
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!valid){
        document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="block";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="test" action ="#">
        <div id="password-container">
            <input type="text" id= "password" name="password" size="30" onKeyUp="validatePassword(this)"  title=" Password contains 7 -20characters <br/> and upper case and digits." />
        </div>
        <div id="password-error" class="error" style="display:none;">Invalid Password</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

$("#test :input").tooltip({

    // place tooltip on the right edge
    position: "center right",

    // a little tweaking of the position
    offset: [-2, 10],

    // use the built-in fadeIn/fadeOut effect
    effect: "fade",

    // custom opacity setting
    opacity: 0.7

});
```

You can see a working example here

http://jsfiddle.net/ddrYp/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, you won't need to use both the tooltip and password error div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ddrYp/12/

But you may run into problems with this in the future because the tooltips are not uniquely identified. I'm not familiar with the plugin, but if you could add an individual ID to each tooltip, that's fix it for you. Once you do that, you could reference the tooltips by using their ID instead of $(".tooltip")... if you expand this to have multiple inputs when you do `$(".tooltip").append(/*something*/)` or `$(".tooltip").HTML(/*something*/)` you're going to modify every tooltip.. which may not matter, because only one is visible at a time... but it's still an inefficiency issue and a bit of a bug

Here's the example of the [ebay password verification](https://scgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?RegisterEnterInfo) example that you were looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/cFrpz/7/

Comment: Thanks bro! This I really appreciate your help. But Can you give me a small hint on how can I implement a password verification like this https://scgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?RegisterEnterInfo and plz point to password field.

Comment: omg!! I can't believe.. You are a ninja....Thanks a million...I really appreciate your help...

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You are really really helpful. One more question how can I show the tooltip only onclick or onfous?

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: u r welcome.If it helped you you can accept the answer by just checking the tick mark on your left.

Comment: Thanks bro..I can't use too many jquery plugins. I'm looking for something how can I show if the validation passes or failes (as it happening on the fly) in the tooltip .Thanks

Comment: It's ok brother we are here to help each other!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<script>
function validatePassword(obj) {
    //rule contains 7 chars and upper case and lower case and digit
    var password = obj.value;
    var numLowers = 0;
    var numCaps = 0;
    var numDigits = 0;
    var valid = true;
    if(password.length > 7) {
        for(i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            var charCode = password.charCodeAt(i);
            if(charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 58 )
            numDigits++;
            else if(charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90 )
            numCaps++;
            else if(charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122 )
            numLowers++;
        }
        if(numDigits < 1 || numCaps < 1 )
        valid = false;
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!valid){
        $(".tooltip").append($("#password-error"));
        document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="block";

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <form id="test" action ="#">
        <div id="password-container">
            <input type="text" id= "password" name="password" size="30" onKeyUp="validatePassword(this)"  title=" Password contains 7 -20characters <br/> and upper case and digits." />

        </div>
<div id="password-error" class="error" style="display:none;">Invalid Password</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddrYp/9/

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro. I want to show the invalid password message in the tooltip, rather than left.

Comment: Greg I've one more question, if you don't mind could you please advice me how to do this,I want something on this page https://scgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?RegisterEnterInfo and plz click on password filed. How can we do that?

Comment: You mean the little strength bar at the right ? Look for password strength checker on google, but what I think about this :  password with a lot of word like : "I like to share my meal with a horse" is better and safer than %bob1A3f. Look at this : http://www.enterpriseirregulars.com/41747/password-strength-and-security/

Comment: Maybe you could do another question for the ebay like password tooltip

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but it should be fine. From your working example, replace this:

```
if(!valid){
    document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="block";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("password-error").style.display="none";
}
```

with this:

```
$tooltip = $(".tooltip"); 
if(!valid && $tooltip.find("div.error").length < 1){
  $tooltip.append("<div class='error'>"+$("#password-error").html()+"</div>");
}
else if(valid) {
  $tooltip.find(".error").remove();
}
```

Comment: Yeah..Its good.But it repeats all the error messages like if i type 6 letter it shows 6 invalid password plz check http://jsfiddle.net/ddrYp/10/

Comment: I'm really confused now, ur solution too is good..Is there any way how we can see the validations on the fly something like this password filed https://scgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?RegisterEnterInfo